# How is a screencast-utility developed programmatically?

Tags: video-capture, software-design, screencast

How do screencast-programs like [Kazaam](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Kazam/) actually record a screen from a technical perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Screencastsoftware like [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) make use of
the [MIT Shared Memory Extension](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xextproto/shm.html) of the X-Server on Linux-Operating system.
This extension is meant for exchanging pixel-data of the entire windowing-system between clients (like screencast-software)
and the server of the x windowing system via interprocess-communication